# Volume resets itself all the time

Tags: volume

Don't know why and at what moment - but phone volume (ringer) always seems to reset itself to 15. I like to keep it at 30 (max)

Phone: Nokia Lumia 925

Comment: Does it give you any kind of dialog or message saying that it happens, or do you just find it at 15?

Comment: Just find it at 15. I can't relate it to anything special. I just find myself constantly setting volume up. Not sure when it happened. Will monitor..

Comment: Do you notice this after using a particular app?

Comment: No. I _feel_ like it happens after charging. Or maybe when it goes to "energy saving". I will monitor it for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume will always revert to a default level after a restart. This isn't a bug but a so called "safety feature" to prevent hearing damage if we should accidentally forget to lower the volume when listening to music through a headset/ear buds.

It's in the tutorial somewhere but can't find it now.